# How can I convert a MIFARE reader to a 125 kHz one?

Tags: can, mifare

I have a MIFARE access reader.
However, it uses a proprietary protocol to the controller (it's called Hi-O and it's some encrypted sort of CAN bus, when you flip the "initialize" DIP switch in the access controller, it somehow negotiates an encryption key for all devices on the CAN network).

I want to convert this reader to 125 kHz. The idea is to do the following:

EM4102 reader → Microcontroller → [CIRCUIT] → Antenna output of MIFARE reader. (by disconnecting the MIFARE reader's current antenna).

How should [CIRCUIT] look, so I can from microcontroller emulate a MIFARE card straight in the antenna output?
I do understand that the field power in the antenna might not be enough to power everything, but I do have access to +12 V in the reader so power supply is no problem.

Note that I do not want to emulate a loose MIFARE card, I want to send the emulation straight into the reader's antenna connector by removing the antenna, so this means another conversion circuit is required than if you would actually have 2 coils.

Another solution would be to tap into the CAN bus and "emulate" the reader and corresponding MIFARE UID when a 125 kHz card is scanned, but that would require knowledge of the HI-O protocol, and I haven't found a specification on it yet.

Comment: It must emulate a loose MIFARE card and possibly also an antenna.

Comment: @user253751 I dont think its neccessary. Somehow it must be possible to emulate the card straight into the coil of the reader. Im thinking of a resistor and transistor over the coil of the reader, and that would make it possible to send data TO the reader. And then some way to detect the coil amplitude to read data FROM the reader.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible to emulate the card straight into the reader. By emulating the card, and the coil. You can't do it without emulating the card because how else do you calculate when to send a 1 and when to send a 0? Yes, you can probably use a circuit similar to how cards and readers already work

Comment: @user253751 of course I must emulate the MIFARE protocol. What I meant was that I want to skip the coils and send data directly into the reader, kind of a physically connected, and not inductively connected, MIFARE card.